# get all rows from the start date to end date inclusive with QueryDSL(Mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, date, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl, predicate

I have this queryDSL query:

```
    QReport report = QReport.report;
    BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();

    if (startDate != null) {
        builder.and(report.modificationDate.after(startDate));
    }

    if (endDate != null) {
        builder.and(report.modificationDate.before(endDate));
    }
```

But if I want to find rows from **`09/04/2018`** to **`09/04/2018`** it doesn't work.
Or from **09/04/2018** to **09/05/2018** - only **09/04/2018** rows are found.

I can add **23.59.59** time to `endDate` but maybe there is some option in query DSL for this?

For example - get all rows from the start date to end date inclusive

Answer (score 1):

A `TemporalExpression` is a `LiteralExpression` which is a `ComparableExpression` in QueryDSl. `TemporalExpression#before` is just an alternative to `ComparableExpression#lt` (for less-than). `ComparableExpression` also has `loe(...)` (for less-than-or-equal).

So you could change your code to `report.modificationDate.loe(endDate)`.